# Regex expression to bold using asterisks

Tags: regex, bold

I have a question regarding using a regular expression to bold text within a string using asterisks.

The other questions on this topic work well for simple scenarios however we have encountered some issues.

Our particular scenario is for asterisks to be replaced with `<bold></bold>` tags.
It must also be able to handle multiple asterisks as well as an uneven number of asterisks.

Our example input text is as follows;

`string exampleText1 = "**** PLEASE NOTE *** Testing, *nuts*, **please note..., test";`

`string exampleText2 = "**Test text (10)";`

Our current regex is as follows;

`Regex _boldRegex  = new Regex(@"(\*)+([^*?$]+)+(\*)");`

`string value = _boldRegex.Replace(exampleText1, @"<bold>$2</bold>");`

Example 1 should show `"<bold> PLEASE NOTE </bold> Testing, <bold>nuts</bold>, *please note..., test"` where the groups of asterisks are treated as single asterisks and an unfinished tag is ignored.

Example 2 crashes the program because it expects a 'closing' asterisk. It should show `"*Text text (10)"`

Can anyone help by suggesting a new regex, bearing in mind the ability to handle groups of asterisks and also an uneven number of asterisks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a parser / some kind of stack and count the asterisks programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you examle data, you might use an optional part with a capture group to capture the repeated character class without newlines between 1 or more `*`

In the callback of replace, you can test for the existence of group 1, and do the replacements based on that.

```php
\*+(?:([^*?$\n\r]+)\*+)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\*+` Match 1+ times `*`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `[^*?$\n\r]+` Match 1+ times any char other than the listed in the character class
  - `)` Close group 1
  - `\*+` Match 1+ times `*`
- `)?` Close on capture group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z7kmo8/1).

For example

```
Regex _boldRegex  = new Regex(@"\*+(?:([^*?$\n\r]+)\*+)?");
string exampleText1 = @"**** PLEASE NOTE *** Testing, *nuts*, **please note..., test
**Test text (10)";
string value = _boldRegex.Replace(exampleText1, m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? String.Format("<bold>{0}</bold>", m.Groups[1].Value) : "*"
);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output

```
<bold> PLEASE NOTE </bold> Testing, <bold>nuts</bold>, *please note..., test
*Test text (10)
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I require perfectly!